QML TextArea and ScrollView combination has a buggy result in after resizing
Here is the code snippet causes the issue:
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ScrollView
    {
        id: scroll
        anchors.fill: parent

        anchors.rightMargin: 50

        TextArea
        {
            id: textArea
        }
    }

    TextField
    {
        anchors.left: scroll.right
        background: Rectangle
        {
            color: "yellow"
        }

    }
}

I have added some lines to my TextArea like this:

Then I have lost the focus by clicking yellow textfield and then I have just resized the mainwindow vertically and I got this weird situation. My below lines are not seen anymore, if i click to TextArea once more they are coming back.

I have also found a solution but it looks like ugly to me. I have added a line to ScrollView and fixed the issue:
        onHeightChanged: textArea.update()

